# Running a x86 server inside a x64 library using C++ (MSVC)

Tags: c++, cmake, build, x86-64, 32-bit

I have the following problem I have been working on:

I need to make a 32bit (x86) library dll play well with a more complex library that leverages it but works in 64bit (x64). The way that I have decided to make this is through a TCP server (instead of the recommended COM) for other reasons that are not relevant. The problem I have is that I can't get the compiler to be happy and build all of it in one go. I am working with CMake to make the build with MSVC 2019 compiler.

I have been scouring SO and the CMake forums searching for a solution but to no avail. From what I have been able to understand, ninja (from CMake) is unable to work with 32bit but when changing the CMakePresets.json to a Win32 system it still complains the same way and it seems it cannot compartmentalize what needs to be built in 64 and what in 32.

Is this something that is straight up not doable or do I have to modify my setup in some way?

Comment: A 64-bit system can run both 32 and 64-bit processes. But a 64-bit process can't load a 32-bit DLL.  So just to be clear... you are trying to build a 32-bit exe to host your 32-bit DLL, yes? (And build the DLL itself too?)

Comment: @selbie Indeed. The 32-bit side of the project will create a server for the operations of that 32-bit dll. The rest of the application is 64 bit, including the client who requests the information from the server.

Comment: CMake doesn't support switching between architectures. Either call cmake twice with different toolchains or use ExternalProject

Comment: @Osyotr Thank you very much for the tip about ExternalProject. I was unaware it and it might make it possible to build the project. However, my question is also about the environment: How can I force CMake to use a build system for 32-bit and one for 64-bit? Even if the project is External I still cannot see a way to do this...

Comment: To answer my own question on this... You can tecnically do this but depends on the compiler and other issues. 

In the end, I managed to make what I wanted to do but with a completely separate project - NOT with CMake. This is because I was unable to get it working without engaging ninja (which is only x64) in the process.